# Java: I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting a NullPointerException here

Tags: java, list, dictionary, nullpointerexception, set

I'm creating a console-based Evil Hangman program. Instead of selecting a word at the beginning of the game, a list of words is progressively narrowed down by selecting out words that contain letters that the user inputs.

This is a pretty common assignment, so I'm sure that you've heard of something similar before.

Here is the specification, in case if you need more clarification.

[Specification](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/15wi/homework/5/spec.pdf)

Necessary file and client for compilation:

[File](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/15wi/homework/5/dictionary.txt)

[HangmanMain](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse143/15wi/homework/5/HangmanMain.java)

The problematic method in this particular class is the record() method, which is by far the most difficult method to program in this assignment.
There are two main problems that I'm observing:

a) There is the following NullPointerException that I can't figure out the reason for. It's occurring at a line where a word is being added to the list. As far as I can tell, the word and the list should both exist and are both initialized. It's not a matter of the list not containing a word or of the list not being properly initialized. It seems to only happen after the second user input.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at HangmanManager.record(HangmanManager.java:66)
at HangmanMain.playGame(HangmanMain.java:59)
at HangmanMain.main(HangmanMain.java:39)
```

b) The NullPointerException is probably caused at my earlier attempts to fix another problem. Before the NullPointerException occurred, I was experiencing problems determining why the word selected by the program wasn't following the expected output. No matter what I did, the word selected by the program at the end of the traversal would always be "aa." Even when I had deliberately chose 'a' as a guess, which should have effectively filtered out "aa" as a choice, it still showed up.

Here is my program so far.

```
import java.util.*;
public class HangmanManager {
private String pattern;
private int length;
private int max;
private SortedSet<Character> guessesMade;
private Set<String> words;
private Set<String> currentWords;
private Map<String, Set<String>> patternMap;

public HangmanManager(List<String> dictionary, int length, int max){
    if (length < 1 || max < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.length = length;
    this.max = max;
    words = new TreeSet<String>();
    for (String word : dictionary){
        if (word.length() == length){
            words.add(word);
        }
    }
    currentWords = new TreeSet<String>();
    guessesMade = new TreeSet<Character>();
    patternMap = new TreeMap<String, Set<String>>();
    pattern = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        pattern += "- ";
    }

}
public Set<String> words(){
    return words;
}
public int guessesLeft(){
    return max - guessesMade.size();
}
public SortedSet<Character> guesses(){
    return guessesMade;
}
public String pattern(){
    if (words.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There are no words.");
    }
    return pattern;
}

public int record(char guess){
    if (guessesLeft() < 1 || words.isEmpty()){
        throw new IllegalStateException();  
    }
    if (!words.isEmpty() && guessesMade.contains(guess)) { 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    guessesMade.add(guess);
    int largestOccurences = 0;
    for (String word: words){
        System.out.println(word);
        System.out.println(words.size());
        if (patternMap.containsKey(pattern)){   
            System.out.println("patternMap contains pattern");
            largestOccurences = generatePattern(word, guess);
            currentWords.add(word);
            currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);
            patternMap.put(pattern, currentWords);          
        } else {
            currentWords.add(word);
            patternMap.put(pattern, currentWords);
        }
    }
    words = findFamily();
    return largestOccurences;
}
private Set<String> findFamily(){
    int maxSize = 0;
    Map <String, Integer> patternCount = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String key : patternMap.keySet()){
        patternCount.put(key, patternMap.get(key).size());
            if (patternMap.get(key).size() > maxSize){
                maxSize = patternMap.get(key).size();
                pattern = key;
            } else if (patternMap.get(key).size() == maxSize){
                if (key.length() >= pattern.length()){
                    pattern = key;
                    maxSize = patternMap.get(key).size();
                }
            }
        }
    System.out.println("Current pattern: " + pattern);
    return patternMap.get(pattern);
}

private int generatePattern(String s, char guess) {
    int count = 0;
    pattern = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if (s.charAt(i) == guess){
                pattern += guess + " ";
                count++;
            } else {
                pattern += "- ";
            }
        }
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: It would be very sweet of you if you'll show us where is line 39 in HangmanMain.java

Comment: Not posted exact code... were is main method and what arguments you have passed ?

Comment: The error that I'm talking about occurs in line 66 of HangmanManager.java, which is my program.

Comment: I provided the main method in my post as the client file, along with the dictionary.txt that is necessary for the program to run.

Comment: Please kindly tell us which is line66

Comment: This error occurs in the record() method, on the line that says "    currentWords.add(word);"

Comment: It is people-who-don't-know-how-to-use-debug invasion on SO

Comment: How are you calling this code?

Comment: I think your `word` is null in one of the iterations. As TreeSet doesn't allow null values, you're getting that NPE

Comment: The methods of the code are being called in the client file that I provided in my post.

Comment: The dictionary which you use to initialize HangmanManager should not contain **null** values.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint at line 66 and check what is null? (I think you're getting -1'ed because homework questions are generally frowned upon on SO... however, we can help you track down your problem.)

Comment: The exception is thrown in the class HangmainMain, but you only show the code for HangmanManager.

Comment: He attached `HangmanMain` in the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with `patternMap`.

```
 if (patternMap.containsKey(pattern))
    {   
        System.out.println("patternMap contains pattern");
        largestOccurences = generatePattern(word, guess);
        //=> generatePattern changes the global variable pattern, so it may 
        //not be contained in patternMap anymore

        currentWords.add(word);
        currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);//since pattern was changed, 
                                               //patternMap return null and  
                                         //you get NullPointerException on 
                                         //the next iteration of the loop

        patternMap.put(pattern, currentWords);          
    }
```

You need to make sure that the newly changed `pattern` is present in the `patternMap` when you are calling `currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);`. Otherwise, you will get `null`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I actually noticed that pattern was null at this point in the program, but I didn't think it was relevant because the exception was being thrown at a line where pattern was not being used. Only currentWords and word are used at line 66. Does this not matter?

Comment: You are reassigning `currentWords` with `currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);`. This makes `currentWords` being null. So when the next enty of the loop `for (String word: words)` is pulled, `currentWords` is null and you crash at line 66.

Comment: Oh, okay, that makes sense. Sorry. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check for null before assigning the value..
 currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);

replace this with
 if(patternMap.get(pattern)!=null)
 currentWords = patternMap.get(pattern);

chk this out...if you have any such assignments do the null checks..

Good Luck!